# How to join tables on regex

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, join, pattern-matching

Say I have two tables msg for messages and mnc for mobile network codes.
They share no relations. But I want to join them

```
SELECT msg.message,
    msg.src_addr,
    msg.dst_addr,
    mnc.name,
FROM "msg"
JOIN "mnc"
ON array_to_string(regexp_matches(msg.src_addr || '+' || msg.dst_addr, '38(...)'), '') = mnc.code
```

But query fails with error:

```
psql:marketing.sql:28: ERROR:  argument of JOIN/ON must not return a set
LINE 12: ON array_to_string(regexp_matches(msg.src_addr || '+' || msg...
```

Is there a way to do such join? Or am I moving wrong way?

Comment: This is likely to be extremely inefficient (not using indexes, having to compare every single row).

Comment: @TheifMaster, not necessarily, it could use function based indexes such as how upper is mentioned [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createindex.html)

Comment: @z4y4ts, Is there something significant about the regular expression `38(...)` or is it just there as an example of a regular expression? As far as I can see, it just looks for any occurence of 38 followed by any 3 other characters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A very odd way to join. Every match on one side is combined with every row from the other table ...

`regexp_matches()` is probably the wrong function for your purpose. You want a simple [regular expression match (`~`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP). Actually, the [`LIKE` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) will be **faster**:

#### Presumably fastest with `LIKE`

```sql
SELECT msg.message
     , msg.src_addr
     , msg.dst_addr
     , mnc.name
FROM   mnc
JOIN   msg ON msg.src_addr LIKE ('%38' || mnc.code || '%')
           OR msg.dst_addr LIKE ('%38' || mnc.code || '%')
WHERE  length(mnc.code) = 3;
```

In addition, you only want `mnc.code` of exactly 3 characters.

#### With regexp match

You *could* write the same with regular expressions but it will most definitely be slower. Here is a working example close to your original:

```sql
SELECT msg.message
     , msg.src_addr
     , msg.dst_addr
     , mnc.name
FROM   mnc
JOIN   msg ON (msg.src_addr || '+' || msg.dst_addr) ~ (38 || mnc.code)
           AND length(mnc.code) = 3;
```

This also requires `msg.src_addr` and `msg.dst_addr` to be `NOT NULL`.

The second query demonstrates how the additional check `length(mnc.code) = 3` can go into the `JOIN` condition or a `WHERE` clause. Same effect here.

#### With `regexp_matches()`

You *could* make this work with [`regexp_matches()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```sql
SELECT msg.message
     , msg.src_addr
     , msg.dst_addr
     , mnc.name
FROM   mnc
JOIN   msg ON EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM   regexp_matches(msg.src_addr ||'+'|| msg.dst_addr, '38(...)', 'g') x(y)
    WHERE  y[1] = mnc.code
    );
```

But it will be slow in comparison.

**Explanation:**
Your `regexp_matches()` expression just returns an array of all captured substrings of the **first** match. As you only capture one substring (one pair of brackets in your pattern), you will exclusively get **arrays with one element**.

You get **all matches** with the additional "globally" switch **`'g'`** - but in multiple rows. So you need a sub-select to test them all (or aggregate). Put that in an `EXISTS` - semi-join and you arrive at what you wanted.

Maybe you can report back with a **performance test** of all three?
Use [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) for that.

Comment: Hi @erwin, thank you for solid answer. Here are some performance numbers https://gist.github.com/1691021 Just as you said, query with LIKE is the fastest one, followed by regexp and  regexp_matches(). No surprises though, but I think real numbers can be interesting.

Comment: @z4y4ts: Thanks for the feedback. Exactly as expected, but it's always good to verify. :)

Comment: Agreed it is a weird way to join tables however this is useful if you are ever running a one-off query and want to find identifiers for each table via a name or other vague connection.

Comment: What I didn't know myself is where to put the parentheses. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that [`regexp_matches`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) could return one or more rows.

Comment: Actually, without the `'g'` switch, `regexp_matches()` returns exactly **1** row with an array of all captured substrings of the **first** match. However, the OP would need the `'g'` switch to get that result for **all** matches.

Comment: It **could** return multiple rows and that's what's important to the parser hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "substring" instead, which extracts a substring given a regex pattern.

```
SELECT msg.message,
    msg.src_addr,
    msg.dst_addr,
    mnc.name
FROM "msg"
JOIN "mnc"
ON substring(msg.src_addr || '+' || msg.dst_addr from '38(...)') = mnc.code
```

Comment: This is going to fail because `substring()` only returns the first match, but one of the additional matches could be `mnc.code`. Consider: `SELECT substring('38foo+38bar', '38(...)') = 'bar'`. That's probably the reason why the OP tried `regexp_matches()`.