# Correct spelling mistakes in a column based on another table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

My postgresql table has a (cityname) column. the values in the (cityname) column has some spelling mistakes. Each and every record of column (cityname) needs to be corrected. Another table has a column that contains all correct city names. Based on this table the spelling mistakes of the first table are needed to be corrected.

Comment: Can you please include the code you've already written, and explain which part of it is giving you a problem?

Comment: Select  * from table_1 A,table_2 B where A.add3=B.address and custno not in
(Select custno  from table_1 A,table_2 B where A.add2=B.address  and custno not in
(Select custno  from table_1 A,table_2 B where A.add1=B.address ))  and custno in  
(Select distinct(B.custno) from table a,table b
 where acctstat in (1,2) and A.custno = B.custno)

Comment: with the above query i am able to join only few records

Comment: Perhaps you need to look into something like [Levenshtein distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) - these can help you identify the most likely match for a misspelled word based on the number of changes required to change one string into another.

Answer (score 0):

You need a column which can relate rows in table A (with the mistakes) to table B with the correct data. Lets assume you have the city_id column which does this job.

```
update table_A  
set add1 = table_b.correct_add1  
from table_A as j_table_A  
join table_B on table_B.city_id = table_A.city_id  
where j_table_A.primary_key_column = table_A.primary_key_column
```

you basically reference table_A twice. there is no good reason to do this, but I have found that if you need to pull data from joins, then during an update this is the easiest way.

Edited after comment:
Since you have no good way of associating the correct data to the data that needs fixing (like a city_id), then you need to work on your join condition and perhaps introduce a regex. there is a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679079/how-to-join-tables-on-regex) which may be of some use

Comment: i dont have a coloumn which relates both tables apart from the coloumn which has citynames.i need to join both tables using the coloumn named cityname