# Maven version ordering

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, maven, natural-sort

I have a table of Maven projects. Each project has a number of parameters and a version number.

When I select from the table I should only get the highest version, but due to the way maven versions look, this is tricky. This is the query I have so far:

```
select id, group_id as group, artifact_id as artifact
from (
   select 
     p.group_id,
     p.artifact_id,
     p.id,
     rank() over (partition by p.group_id, p.artifact_id order by p.version desc)
   from projects p
   ) as ranked
   where ranked.rank = 1
```

This does not give the highest version as the version does not follow a alphanumeric ordering.
[The version format is described here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html).

The gist is that a version could be `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`, where `1` (major), `2` (minor), `3` (incremental) are numbers and should be ordered as such and `SNAPSHOT` (qualifier) is a string. If the version does not follow this format, it should be treated as a string.

Is this doable in PostgreSQL?

Comment: `If the version does not follow this format, it should be treated as a string.` .. That's not defining it. How would that be sorted then? Best add a test case with the desired sort order to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: That's true, and I paraphrased the definition in my link slightly. What it says is: "If your version number does not match this format, then the entire version number is treated as being the Qualifier." I interpret this as null values for major, minor and incremental. I think the sort order with least surprise is sorting nulls first, meaning versions not following the format should be first (properly formatted > inproperly formatted). Another reason is that if the reverse is true the an incorrectly formatted version would always be interpreted as the newest.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string. Like:

```sql
SELECT version
     , substring(version, '^(\d+)')::int AS major
     , substring(version, '^\d+\.(\d+)')::int AS minor
     , substring(version, '^\d+\.\d+\.(\d+)')::int AS incremental
     , substring(version, '-(.+)$') AS qualifier
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('1.2.3-SNAPSHOT')
   , ('2-FOO')
   , ('2-BAR')
   , ('2.1-BAR')
   , ('13.5.6-SNAPSHOT')
   , ('13.11.11-SNAPSHOT')
   ) x(version)
ORDER  BY major NULLS LAST
        , minor NULLS FIRST
        , incremental NULLS FIRST
        , qualifier NULLS FIRST;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=df130d91f15d13434f0c30015450947f)*

- `substring(version, '^(\d+)')` ... use [`substring()` with regular expression patterns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) to parse.
  `^` ... start of string
  `()` ... capturing parentheses
  `\d` ... class shorthand for digits
- `substring(version, '^(\d+)')::int` ... cast to integer to sort as number
- [`major NULLS LAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) ... versions without number go last (my assumption).
- `minor NULLS FIRST` ... `2` comes before `2.1`
- `NULLS LAST` is the default ins `ASC` (ascending) sort order in [`ORDER BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) and can be omitted.

You can use these expressions in `ORDER BY` directly (without adding them to the `SELECT` list). Just to demonstrate.

### Advanced solution

For even more complex rules, you might want to use [`regexp_matches()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) - or, preferably, [**`regexp_match()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) in Postgres 10 or later:

```sql
SELECT *
     , part[1] AS p1, part[2] AS p2, part[3] AS p3, part[4] AS p4
     , part[5] AS p5, part[6] AS p6, part[7] AS p7
FROM  (
   SELECT test_id, version
        , regexp_match(version
                     , '^(?:(\d+)(\w*)\.?(\d*)(\w*)\.?(\d*)(\w*))?(?:\-*(\w+))?') AS part
   FROM  (
      VALUES
        (1, '1.2.3-SNAPSHOT')
      , (2, '2-FOO')
      , (3, '2')
      , (4, '2-BAR')
      , (5, '2.1-BAR')
      , (6, '13.5.6-SNAPSHOT')
      , (7, '13.11.11-SNAPSHOT')
      , (8, '13.11a.11-SNAPSHOT')
      , (9, '13.11b.11')
      , (10, 'Test')
      , (11, 'TEST2')
      , (12, '1a')
      , (13, '1a.1a.1a-foo')
      , (14, '1a.1a.1a-')
      , (15, '1a.1a.1b-foo')
      , (16, 'sp9d8hgf')
      , (17, '2a-BAR')
      , (18, '2.1a-BAR')
      , (19, '2.1ab-BAR')
      , (20, 'incorrect1.2-foo')
      ) x(test_id, version)
   ) sub
ORDER  BY NULLIF(part[1], '')::int NULLS FIRST
        , NULLIF(part[2], '')      NULLS FIRST
        , NULLIF(part[3], '')::int NULLS FIRST
        , NULLIF(part[4], '')      NULLS FIRST
        , NULLIF(part[5], '')::int NULLS FIRST
        , NULLIF(part[6], '')      NULLS FIRST
        , part[7]                  NULLS FIRST;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=15fa46b7a3454241dda5e43ad2d51720)*

This deals with [all additional rules from your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775211/maven-version-ordering#comment27735433_18775357).

`regexp_matches()` is a powerful tool, but you *need* basic understanding of regular expressions. Test if in doubt.
Note in particular:

- Not adding the `g` switch. [More here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8680446/939860)
- `NULLIF(part[1],'')::int` ... non-matches are listed as empty strings in the array. Need to be converted to `NULL` before casting to `integer`

Be aware of the difference between [*capturing* `()` and *non-capturing* parentheses `(:?)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE). The former also *report* a match, while the latter does not.

Comment: Nice solution, way better than my best attempt. One fault I can find is if major, minor or incremental is not a digit, e.g. in 13a.5.6-SNAPSHOT the 'a' will not get picked up by the regex. Another is if the format is not correct at all (e.g. if the version is just a string like 'asffdgsdgdg') then it gets sorted last, meaning it will always be  interpreted as the newest version (i know this part was unclear in my question). So both of those should actually be first (correctly formatted > incorrectly formatted)

Comment: @Casper: Note the added advanced solution.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I read the manual about (?:re). (a "non-capturing" set of parenthese"). I just found It so hard to understand. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @jian: "Capturing" parentheses also *report* a match (where applicable), while "non-capturing" do not - they just delimit an "atom" in the pattern.